# flutter bloc loaded state getting empty

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

**Description:**

I have two BLoCs, ProductsBloc and TestListBloc, in my Flutter application. The issue arises when I call `TestListBloc` inside `ProductsBloc` and expect it to update accordingly. Here's a brief overview of the flow:

1. Inside `ProductsBloc`, I trigger the `FetchTestListEvent`.
2. The `TestListBloc` processes the event and enters the `TestListLoadedState`.

**Problem:**

Even though the `TestListBloc` is updated and in the loaded state, when I try to access it in the UI, it appears empty. The UI seems unaware of the changes happening inside the `TestListBloc`.

**Code Snippet:**

```dart
// Inside ProductsBloc
class ProductsBloc extends Bloc {
  final TestListBloc testListBloc;

  ProductsBloc({required this.testListBloc}) : super(InitialState());

  void someFunction() {
    // Triggering the event inside ProductsBloc
    testListBloc.add(FetchTestListEvent());
  }
}

// Inside TestListBloc
class TestListBloc extends Bloc {
  TestListBloc() : super(InitialState());

  @override
  Stream mapEventToState(event) async* {
    if (event is FetchTestListEvent) {
      // Processing the event and updating state
      yield TestListLoadedState(testList: /* updated test list */);
    }
  }
}

// Trying to access TestListBloc in the UI
void updateUI() {
  final testList = testListBloc.state; // Appears empty, even after FetchTestListEvent
  // Rest of the UI update logic
}
```

What could be causing the UI to not recognize the changes in TestListBloc even after the FetchTestListEvent is triggered inside ProductsBloc? Am I missing something in the way BLoCs interact with each other in this scenario?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: > "even after the FetchTestListEvent is triggered inside ProductsBloc"
Where does this happen? You have it setup so that the fetch happens inside `someFunction()`, but nothing in your code sample is calling that function. Another concern is that, even if `someFunction()` is being called offscreen, because the fetch is `async`, you have to make sure that the fetch is complete, and the state has actually been updated to `...Loaded...` before trying to access it